# Appearing text depends on language on site (js)

Tags: javascript, joomla, internationalization, multilingual

On my site http://www.incognito.preart.grandhost.pl/ when You enter any page there is a link back to main menu (when You hover title). Site is in 5 languages. But the text is only in English. In need to have text "Back to menu" in every language.

Code of .js:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(document).ready(function() {
    j("body").css("display", "none");
    j("body").fadeIn(1000);
    j("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        j("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });     
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }

    var prevText = j('div#lContent h2 a').text();
    j('div#lContent h2 a').hover(function(){

        j(this).text('Back to menu');
    }, function(){
        j(this).text(prevText);
    });
});
```

I think I need something like this:

- if in url there is `/en/` show "Back to menu"
- if in url there is `/fr/` show "retour au menu"
  and so on.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Relying solely on JavaScript for language delivery is a bad idea.

Comment: Languages are in joomla setting, not JavaScript. JavaScript shows only one text on site: "Back to menu"

Answer (score 0):

As BenM said, doing localization on JS is not the best of ideas.

Though if you really insist, you can do it this way. In your backend, php code - create a global js variable that holds the language.
let's say,

```
var LANG = "EN"; // or you might want to add that as an attribute to an object
```

In your JS code, create a lookup object

```
var BACK_TXT = {
  "EN" : "Back to Menu",
  "PL" : "I don't speak Polish : (",
  "GR" : "Pisw re"
};
```

and when you set the text instead of doing *j(this).text('Back to menu');* do

```
j(this).text( BACK_TXT[ LANG ] );
```

adding checks for valid languages would be sane to have too

```
if( !parent_obj.LANG )
     parent_obj.LANG = "EN";
```

Just be wary with the way you lay your code and document it well, because something like this could easily become hard to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript to control the language is a very bad idea. What do you think will happen if the user has javascript turned off? Even thought this is something that is considered silly, good web developers always take it into consideration.

I think [JoomFish](http://www.joomfish.net/en/downloads) might be what you're looking for.

Hope this helps